# Is there a way to get the email adresses of people currently working on spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps

There is a "Edited By" column in my sheet. So I want put the email addresses of people who edited the associated row.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var sheetName = ws.getSheetName();
  ws.getRange(r, colName2colNumber(sheetName,"Edited by")).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Above code block are working fine while I (owner of the spreadsheet) am working on sheet. However, It doesn't work on other people I shared the sheet with by editor privilages. I think onEdit function has some restrictions on shared spreadsheets.

So firstly I wonder that why the onEdit doesn't work on shared spreadsheets?

If there is some restrictions about onEdit, is there some other functions, or some other ways generally, which makes me put the editors email on "Edited by" column?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an installable trigger instead of a simple trigger.

```
function myfunction(e){
  e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.getSheet().getRange(1,1,1,e.range.getSheet().getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf("Edited by")).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());//This assumes that the header row is the top row
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts It says that installable triggers runs as user who created the triger.

Comment: Yes. So each user gets to choose whether they wish to authenticate or not.  So that you can't take their data without them knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser):

> **getActiveUser()**
>
> Gets information about the current user. If security policies do not
>   allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank
>   string.

In this case, the simple trigger onEdit() does not runs the script because the user can't give explicit permissions to it. [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) won't fix the issue either.

An option would be creating an [Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview), so others would install it by their side and grant permissions to it.